# How to prevent inserting value greater than the number which user enters in text field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meteor

I had a text field called premium where the user can enter max of 10 digits.After they click submit another text field called deposit opens where it can enter a max of 7 digits..But I want to give a condition where the user cant enter the deposit more than premium..
Example:

`If premium=111
 Deposit should be <=111`

If the deposit is more than premium onchange the value should be changed back to premium i.e., to 111

Can someone help me in this I got stuck.
Thanks.
Jsfiddle for above:https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/28556/

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check once and upvote if you find it helpful

https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/28558/

```
             function TodoCtrl($scope) {

                $scope.hide=false;
                $scope.submit = function() {
                   $scope.hide=true;
                   if($scope.deposit && parseInt($scope.deposit)>parseInt($scope.premium)){

                     $scope.deposit = $scope.premium;
                  }
               };

             }
```

Comment: @ H Varma ..  please check the JS FIDDLE link

Answer (score 0):

hi you can add tyr with following code as a attribute to deposit input field. And give id "preminum" to premium input field.

```
onkeypress="return Number(this.value()+""+event.key) <= Number($('#premium').value());"
```

This won't allow user to enter value more than premium.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
$scope.$watch('deposit', function(newVal, oldVal){     
    if(newVal && newVal*1 > $scope.premium*1)
        $scope.deposit = $scope.premium;    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Html5 supports min and max with number inputs. For example: 
`<input type="number" name="deposit" min="1" max="111">`
Anyway it is good to check all user inputs on server side.